# While using onehot library in R, I get an error in the model.matrix command

Tags: r, one-hot-encoding

For label encoding I am using `model.matrix` from library `onehot` in R. 
The data set is available [here](https://datahack.analyticsvidhya.com/contest/practice-problem-loan-prediction-iii/download/train-file).

I have renamed the file as `train.csv`
The feature to be encoded is `Education`. It has got two levels, `Graduate` and `Not Graduate`. However on executing the code,

```
library(onehot)

data <- read_csv("train.csv")
set.seed(1234)
datashuffled <- data[sample(1:nrow(data)), ]
datashuffled_Loan_StatusRemoved <- datashuffled %>%
select(-starts_with("Loan_Status"))
features <- datashuffled_Loan_StatusRemoved
sum(is.na(features$Education))
features$Education[features$Education=="Not Graduate"] <- "NotGraduate"
E <- model.matrix(~Education-1,head(features))
```

I get an error as

> Error in contrasts<-(*tmp*, value = contr.funs[1 + isOF[nn]]) : 
>     contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels.

Comment: I am sorry. Can you reply in English?

Comment: @karen Hey thanks! I got it. I am posting the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry it was a typo. I should have used the complete dataset for `model.matrix`. The fix is to replace

```
E <- model.matrix(~Education-1,head(features))
```

to

```
E <- model.matrix(~Education-1,features)
```